# Stub out network on android device

Tags: android

I need to stub out the GSM network on a test android device for testing some parts of an application. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) has a [console](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#console) that can be used to simulate many, many different conditions within the emulator. Have a look a the [telephony emulation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#telephony) section, it may help you to test the necessary parts of your application.

For example, the `gsm` command allows you to enter a command like this:

```
gsm data roaming
```

to simulate your phone roaming. What, specifically, were you going to try to stub out?

Comment: If the tests can be run on the emulator, this is indeed the easiest

Comment: Hi, thats what we are doing on the emulator.But we also run our builds on physical devices and faking the  network on the realdevice would really help. We would liketo fake the  Phone Number and an incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what you mean by "stub out"

If you mean simply disable, you can edit the APN settings (after writing them down!) to break the network, or remove the SIM card (assuming the device uses one)

If you mean use something else instead, most every android phone supports wifi, and you could put whatever monitoring/simulation/etc you want upstream of a cheap wireless access point.

If you want to do it in software... not so easy.  On a rooted phone you could monkey around with the network configuration or drivers, basically as on any other linux only making sure that you don't get in a fight with the android platform, each reverting the other's network settings.